# Selectize.js and Datatables horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, selectize.js

I've got a Datatable with [individual column searching (with select inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).  Now I want to add [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to it, but I can't figure out how to get it right.

When I enable [horizontal scrolling](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html), the pulldown is partly hidden:.

[image: Selectize.js with Datatables and horizontal scrolling]

Very simple example:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><select></selection>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
    });
    $('select').selectize();
} );
</script>
```

I've created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/maa64vw4/3/

I've tried to add a `z-index` to multiple places, but I can't figure out how to get all the select options visible.

How can I prevent the select options from being hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose where the `selectize-dropdown` element should be added. By default, it is appended as a child of the Selectize control:

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md:

> The element the dropdown menu is appended to. This should be 'body' or
>   null. If null, the dropdown will be appended as a child of the
>   Selectize control.

This makes the element in this case (partly) invisible, since the row (`tfoot>tr>td`) has a fixed height.

Setting `dropdownParent` to `body` helps:

```
$('select').selectize({
    "dropdownParent": "body"
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/maa64vw4/4/